# Assign static IP in terraform vsphere_virtual_machine

Tags: terraform, vmware, terraform-provider-vsphere

I am trying to add a vmware machine using vsphere, getting below error. I have followed this document. [Terraform Document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vsphere/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine). I am giving default_ip_address. I am using latest version of terraform. Its a windows box. I am expecting this IP address associated with VM when provisioned. Template one network and IP related settings not valid as I am not using any template.

```
   resource “vsphere_virtual_machine” “vm” {

name             = var.name

resource_pool_id = var.resource_pool_id

datastore_id     = var.datastore_id

host_system_id   = var.host_system_id

folder = var.folder

cpu_hot_add_enabled = var.cpu_hot_add_enabled

enable_disk_uuid = "true"

enable_logging  = "true"

sata_controller_count = var.sata_controller_count

scsi_type = var.scsi_type

wait_for_guest_net_timeout = 5

wait_for_guest_ip_timeout  = 0

wait_for_guest_net_routable = true

default_ip_address = "172.16.16.109"

 

num_cpus = var.num_cpus

memory   = var.memory

memory_hot_add_enabled = var.memory_hot_add_enabled
network_interface {

network_id = data.vsphere_network.network.id

bandwidth_share_level  = var.bandwidth_share_level 
}

disk {

label            = "disk0"

size             = var.disksize

thin_provisioned = "false"

eagerly_scrub    = var.eagerly_scrub

keep_on_remove   = "true"
}

cdrom {

client_device = var.client_device 
}

custom_attributes = {

"${resource.vsphere_custom_attribute.attribute1.id}" = var.contact

"${resource.vsphere_custom_attribute.attribute2.id}" = var.application
}

}

Error: Computed attributes cannot be set
│
│ with vsphere_virtual_machine.vm,
│ on import.tf line 62, in resource “vsphere_virtual_machine” “vm”:
│ 62: default_ip_address = “172.16.16.109”
│
│ Computed attributes cannot be set, but a value was set for
│ “default_ip_address”.
```

Comment: Those arguments are only available when cloning from a template. Do you intend to add that to your resource?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I see, I want to add a static ip while creating the Virtual Machine.

Comment: and you are intending to add template cloning to the virtual machine resource or not?

Comment: @MattSchuchard No, no template cloning. Just create a vm with static ip with other options like, CPU, Memory etc.

Comment: am I using wrong parameter?

Comment: I have updated question using default_ip_address